# Legend graph pie with label to the correpondent slice

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend, pgf-pie

I have this code to a graph pie. And I want the line to correspond to each slice, I already changed the numbers and tried do include \def\stackalignment{l} but is not working.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}

\def\stackalignment{r}
 \newcommand\pielabelon[3][0pt]{%
\abovebaseline[#3]{#2%
    \makebox[-\dimexpr8pt+#1]{\smash{%
            \stackunder{}{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr#3+2.5ex}}}}}
   }
  \newcommand\pielabelunder[3][0pt]{%
\belowbaseline[#3]{#2%
    \makebox[-\dimexpr8pt+#1]{\smash{%
            \stackon{\rule{0pt}{1.3ex}}{\rule{1pt} {\dimexpr#3+2.5ex}}}}}
}


     \newcommand{\slice}[4]{
\pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
\let\midangle\pgfmathresult

% slice
\draw[thick,fill=black!10] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

% outer label
\node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};

% inner label
\pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
\let\temp\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
\let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
\node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3};
     }

     \newcounter{a}
      \newcounter{b}

    \begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

        \newcounter{i}
        \newcounter{j}
        \foreach \p/\t in {
            30/Absolute Return Bonds,
            10/\pielabelon[20pt]{Euro Corporate bonds ($>$10 years) (10\%)}{2.5ex},
            4/\pielabelon[15pt]{Eurozone Equities (4\%)}{2.5ex},
            3/\pielabelon[6pt]{Fixed Interest euro govt Bonds ($>$5years) (3\%)}{1ex},
            48/Global equities,
            2/\pielabelunder{Index-Linked euro govts (AS) (2\%)}{2.5ex},
            3/\pielabelunder{Property (3\%)}{0ex}}
        {
            \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
            \addtocounter{b}{\p}
            \slice{\thea/100*360}
            {\theb/100*360}
            {\ifnum\p>10\relax\p\%\fi}{\t}
        }

        \end{tikzpicture}

      \end{document}
```

Also, is it possible to have the legend in two lines? I tried to add \ \ but didn't work.

Comment: have you considered using the pgf-pie package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie)?

Comment: Please make your code (1) compilable and (2) minimal. You should also rationalise your preamble to avoid loading packages twice. You are loading `pgf-pie`. Do you use it?

Comment: @domenicocamasta I want this pie to be consistent with the other on my work

Comment: @cfr already edit

Comment: Your percentages do not add up to 100 so this can't possibly work, can it?

Comment: @cfr thanks, I already changed, must have copy the wrong one. Could u give me some help? Please

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't really understand what you're trying to do. (Which line?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with the existing code is that it is rather inflexible. You cannot, for example, adjust it easily to draw a line at an angle between a segment and the text labelling it because the lines are not being drawn with TikZ at all. The code is also overly complicated because it insists on using non-TikZ things to create the labels, which then makes it difficult to track their positions because you don't have the anchors you get with a node, for example.

I take it the result wanted is something like the following. However, I'm not at all sure about this because, despite several edits, I'm still not clear what you are trying to do. *Which* line? And *what* about it exactly?

[image: pie chart]

The code below creates the labels as part of the `\slice` macro. I realise that you would prefer consistency with other charts in your document. If this is a one-off, just use a different name for the `\slice` macro and use it here. If, however, this problem applies to many of your diagrams, I would replace the code with this or another Ti*k*Z approach to make things flexible and to simplify the code for transparency and easy of customisation. Preferably, use one of the existing packages available but, failing that, at least use code which you can extend or adapt easily as required.

`stackengine` is impressive and possibly it could be used here. But there is no reason to use it here when Ti*k*Z can do what you need more straightforwardly, flexibly and transparently. There is such a thing as making life hard for yourself for no reason. If you are stuck with inflexible code, it is generally more efficient to cut your losses and replace it with a more flexible solution. It never takes as long as you fear to replace it; it always takes longer than you hope to modify it. That, essentially, is what makes it inflexible in the first place.

Just because you could hammer nails in with a mobile phone doesn't mean you wouldn't be better off nipping to the shops for a decent hammer. You think the trip will take ages. You hope the next five dozen nails will go faster with the phone than the first dozen. Kid yourself not: better get the hammer now rather than later.

Three variables are used in the loop rather than two, but the information required is still less than previously. The first variable is the percentage, as before. The second is the content of the label alone. The third is any vertical adjustment required to avoid clashing text: positive for up and negative for down.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand{\slice}[4]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\midangle{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
  % slice
  \draw[thick,fill=black!10] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;
  outer label
  \node  [label={[name=l \j]\midangle:#3}, yshift=#4] at (\midangle:1.15) {};
  inner label
  \pgfmathsetmacro\innerpos{max(min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0),-.5) +.8}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\labelanchor{ ( \midangle < 90 ) ? "south west" : ( ( \midangle < 180 ) ? "east" : ( ( \midangle < 270 ) ? "north" : "west" ) ) }
  \draw (\midangle:\innerpos) -- (l \j.\labelanchor);
}
\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \p/\t/\n [count=\j] in {%
    30/Absolute Return Bonds/0pt,
    10/Euro Corporate bonds ($>$10 years) (10\%)/0pt,
    4/Eurozone Equities (4\%)/0pt,
    3/Fixed Interest euro govt Bonds ($>$5years) (3\%)/-5pt,
    48/Global equities/0pt,
    2/Index-Linked euro govts (AS) (2\%)/-5pt,
    3/Property (3\%)/0pt
  }
  {
    \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
    \addtocounter{b}{\p}
    \slice{\thea/100*360}
    {\theb/100*360}
    {\t}
    {\n}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

If you want the larger percentages to appear in the segments, I would take the percentages out of the labels completely and add them conditionally as part of `\slice`. However, the chart needs to be scaled up in that case else there is not room for the `10%` label. (Alternatively, you could change the cut-off point for putting labels in the segments - the `30%` and `48%` are not a problem in the smaller chart.)

For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand{\slice}[4]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\midangle{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
  % slice
  \draw[thick,fill=black!10] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;
  \ifnum\p<10
    \def\plabel{#3 (\p\%)}%
    \def\slabel{}%
  \else
    \def\plabel{#3}%
    \def\slabel{\p\%}%
  \fi
  %outer label
  \node  [label={[name=l \j]\midangle:\plabel}, yshift=#4] at (\midangle:1.15) {};
  %inner label
  \pgfmathsetmacro\innerpos{max(min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0),-.5) +.8}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\labelanchor{ ( \midangle < 90 ) ? "south west" : ( ( \midangle < 180 ) ? "east" : ( ( \midangle < 270 ) ? "north" : "west" ) ) }
  \node (slabel \j) at (\midangle:\innerpos) {\slabel};
  \draw (slabel \j) -- (l \j.\labelanchor) ;
}
\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \foreach \p/\t/\n [count=\j] in {%
    30/Absolute Return Bonds/0pt,
    10/Euro Corporate bonds ($>$10 years)/0pt,
    4/Eurozone Equities/0pt,
    3/Fixed Interest euro govt Bonds ($>$5years)/-5pt,
    48/Global equities/0pt,
    2/Index-Linked euro govts (AS)/-5pt,
    3/Property/0pt
  }
  {
    \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
    \addtocounter{b}{\p}
    \slice{\thea/100*360}
    {\theb/100*360}
    {\t}
    {\n}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: chart with segment labels]

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works, but is it possible to have the percentages on the pie for the ones with percentage higher than 10%? I tried to add `{\ifnum\p>10\relax\p\%\fi}` but it gives an error. Because in this case I would like the percentage of Absolute Return Bonds and Global Equities to be inside the pie.

Comment: @MarianadaCosta Please see edit. The chart needs to be bigger to do this with the 10% case, but it is pretty straightforward to just add the percentages as part of the `\slice` command.

Comment: Thanks. And is it also possible to this cases, when the probability is higher than 10% to not have the line to the correspondent slice? I tried to separate the code to be inside the if...else loop but didn't get what I want

Comment: Isn't that what the code you had originally did? `\draw (slabel \j) -- (l \j.\labelanchor) ;` draws the line so you can put it inside a conditional if you wish. (I think this looks a bit odd and would style all the segments the same way for consistency, but that's obviously your call.)

Comment: If you don't have the line for the 10% segment, though, I think it is really not clear which segment the label applies to.

Comment: what I mean is to not have the segment for 30% and 48% (in this case)

Comment: like this: http://imgur.com/nD0sN02

Comment: If you want something that inconsistent, just draw the lines manually because it isn't worth defining an algorithm which says, in effect, if macro has the value 10 do something completely different than in any other case. I find the result really confusing and very untidy looking. Why not just put the 10% in the label by changing the threshold value?

Comment: I have a lot of these graph pies and I think that you are not understanding, what I mean is whenever I have a percentage higher than 11% I have the percentage inside the pie and I don't want the line to theses cases. But I am not managing to get this

Comment: @MarianadaCosta But it is horribly inconsistent. Segments corresponding to less than 10% are formatted one way. That's bad enough if everything else is formatted a second way. But you then want segments corresponding to % greater than or equal to 10 but less than 11 to be formatted a third way. This is really confusing and distracting for readers.